# 3 axis plot in r returns error 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot, axis

I want to make a three axis graph with two different coloured lines. I want to plot two different lists listMontlyConflict and lis against their length (both 216 columns).

I set x originally as length of listMontlyConflict but I get the error message 'x' and 'y' lengths differ. This also occurs when I make x into a range(0: length(listMontlyConflict)). Is this because I cannot plot a list against an integer or range?

This is the output for dput(head(lis))

structure(list(`January 1997` = 0.215277777777778, `February 1997` = 0.2192, 
    `March 1997` = 0.2192, `April 1997` = 0.2192, `May 1997` = 0.2192, 
    `June 1997` = 0.2192), .Names = c("January 1997", "February 1997", 
"March 1997", "April 1997", "May 1997", "June 1997"))

this is the output for dput(head(listMontlyConflict))

structure(list(`January 1997` = 4L, `February 1997` = 8L, `March 1997` = 6L, 
    `April 1997` = 10L, `May 1997` = 7L, `June 1997` = 5L), .Names = c("January 1997", 
"February 1997", "March 1997", "April 1997", "May 1997", "June 1997"
))

```
x <- length(listMontlyConflict)

plot(x,listMontlyConflict,type="l",col="red")

plot(x, lis,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
legend("topleft",col=c("red","blue"),lty=1,legend=c("Conflict Events","Ethnic Fractionalisation"))
```

Comment: Please read up on [ask] and how to create a reproducible example.

Comment: This question completely depends on how `listMonthlyConflict` and `lis` look. Like @heroka said, a reproducible example would be nice. You can give us some data with `dput` (e.g. `dput(head(lis))`)? Otherwise, `str(lis)` would be helpful as well. Finally, in your first `plot` you wrote `X` instead of `x`.

Comment: thanks I saw that but the problem remains. I added the output of head(). Apologies if the question was poorly presented.

Comment: Sorry I have figured it out now. Apologies